# Global maximum for a two times continuously differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

Let $M:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x^2+y^2<1\}\setminus\{(x,0)\in \mathbb R^2, x\in \mathbb R\}$ and $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be two times continuously differentiable.

I want to know whether the restriction $f:\overline{M}\rightarrow \mathbb R$ of $f$ attains its global maximum on $\overline{M}$.

Comment: Is $\bar M$ the closure of $M$? In this case, the domain is compact, and one can apply [Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem).

Comment: Hm yes, but why $f$ needs to by two times continuously differentiable? Thats actually ah task of my course

Comment: You certainly only need continuity to show that $f|_{\bar{M}}$ has a maximum.  I would guess that it certainly is easier to find the maximizing point when $f$ is known to be twice continuously differentiable, in contrast to being given some very strange continuous function.

Comment: It is enough for existence if $f$ is continuous there. However, if the task is to *find* the maximum then you have to use (I guess) KKT conditions where you need differentiability.